# Какие существуют методы организации вёрстки динамических элементов в веб-приложениях?

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, frontend

В этом вопросе рассматривается процесс создания веб-приложений (не важно, на нативном JS или с фреймворками), где в каждом состоянии видны не все элементы или в зависимости от состояния отображение элемента отличается. Например, создание виджета "календарь" (date picker): сам этот виджет появляется только когда его вызывают кликом по полю ввода, да ещё он сам имеет несколько абсолютно спозиционированных страниц, наложенных друг на друга (с днями, месяцами, годами и так далее).

Вопрос такой: как организовать процесс вёрстки подобных элементов? Проблема в том, что для того, чтобы посмотреть, как изменилась, например, страница выбора месяца, нужно после редактирования кода каждый раз вызывать сам календарь, и ещё открывать страницу месяцев (и всё - даже при наличии Live reload).

Я сам использую такой подход:

1. Создаю HTML-страницу без JavaScript-кода только для вёрстки и, собственно, верстаю там все элементы.
2. Создаю HTML-страницу уже с подключением JavaScript-кода и из ранее свёрстанных элементов "собираю" виджет.

Главный недостаток этого метода заключается в том, что на стадии JavaScript-программирования обязательно появится потребность в новых классах, и, может быть атрибутах и ID. Тогда придётся править и исходную вёрстку тоже, иначе между исходной вёрсткой и реальным виджетом образуется очень большая разница и тогда внедрение нового функционала станет проблематичным.

Comment: Вроде расписано все хорошо, но все равно не понятно в чем суть .... напишите "дев-модификатор" класса, при котором календарь будет открыт всегда, все абсолютно спозиционированные элементы будут статично стоять в ряд или столбец (короче что бы все было видно) .... от правок кода в процессе не избежать, даже если хорошо спроектировать, добавление "фич" неизбежно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше описание очень размыто.

1. Верстайте с учетом переносимости, у виджета не должно быть зависимостей от внешней верстки, либо они должны быть минимальны, относитесь к таким вещам как к законченным компонентам.

2.Пишите методы для показа/скрытия виджета, выставление месяца/года тд, т.е. все манипуляции с виджетом только через методы, соответственно оформляйте виджет в виде объект.

3.Верстайте с учетом БЭМ или псевдо-БЭМ.

В дальнейшем во время дебага или написания нового функционала вы можете вызывать эти методы на любой стадии, например при загрузки странице, клике на элемент и тд. в зависимости от ситуации.

P.S: возможно стоит почитать книги по проектированию ПО, даже те которые не относятся к сайтостроению, думаю они смогут вам ответить на подобные вопросы.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!